# Why is grafana displaying 0 on the top of the graph

Tags: grafana

It's hard to describe what's going on so i'll show the graph

[image]

Weirdly, when I only select Busy IOWait it's all fine. The issue is only when other series are visible

Queries used

```
floor(avg(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node-exporter",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
floor(avg(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node-exporter",mode="iowait"}[5m])) * 100)
floor(avg(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node-exporter",mode="user"}[5m])) * 100)
floor(avg(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node-exporter",mode="system"}[5m])) * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have selected "Stack series = 100%" in the panel configuration:

[image]